# Why does my list display output only upto a certain length of input number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, output

I have been trying to solve Codeforces problem No. 313A.  I take an input from the user and convert it into a list. The code works fine till the input number is 11 to 12 digits long. After that, the code gives no output. Here's my code in Python 3:

```
n = int(input())
if(n >= 0):
    print(n)
else:
    if(n <= -10 and n>= -90):
        print(0)
    else:
        n = str(n)
        n.split()
        k = []
        k = n[:len(n) - 1]
        l = []
        l = n[:len(n) - 2] + n[len(n) - 1]
        k = ''.join(k)
        l = ''.join(l)
        k , l = int(k), int(l)
        if(k >= l):
            print(k)
```

Here's the [link](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/313/A) for the problem.

Comment: Could you describe what the code is supposed to do in the body of your question?

Comment: The link that you have submitted is a bit wrong. A ']' comes at the end.

Comment: You sure your program is running fine? I entered -33333333333333333333333333 and got the right output...

Comment: Though your code doesn't do what it is supposed to do, I con't reproduce the problem you describe. Btw, what to you expect `n.split()` to do?

Comment: yeah.. I did input numbers like -3333333333333333 or -4444444444444444444444444444 and the code works fine. so its not a problem of the length of the number. but still I don't understand why it doesn't give output for numbers like -3454334523589262.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille maybe TP meant n.strip() ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an else statement.

```
if(k >= l):
    print(k)
else:
    print(l)
```

Comment: oh..thank you. that's the silliest mistake I can make. :|

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not the best. It's not giving answer because it's only printing out answer when the second last number is smaller than the last number.

For example:
-12947092734023749723847982374 won't print out anything

-12947092734023749723847982347 will give the answer.

You should add:

```
if(k >= l):
    print(k)
else:
    print(l)
```